# count characters in textarea in specific line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

How can i read total characters in specific line ?

i want user only will enter 75 chars in textarea with 5 lines only , means user can only use 5 enters or return, after 5 enter or return he will not be able to enter more chars. so 15 chars in one line.

i can get the current line number with following code, how about calculating total chars in that line onkeypress ?

```
function getLineNumber()
{
    var t = $("#textareaId")[0];
    console.log(t.value.substr(0, t.selectionStart).split("\n").length);
}​
```

Comment: Why won't you check the total length isn't bigger than 75 ?!

Comment: If it's fifteen characters per line, and you have five lines... why not use `<input type="text" maxlength="15" />` * 5?

Comment: if user press 6 enter chars then my design will get disturb in html, so i need to restrict the user only to allow 5 enters

Comment: maxlength="15"  wont work for every browser

Comment: if this is a design issue, you should probably re-think your strategy... think of people who have their font manually up-sized in browser because they cannot read small letters... even 3 lines can be a problem there

Comment: why not use a `<textarea rows="4" cols="15" wrap="hard" maxlength="75">` (potentially with a `maxlength`-polyfill)?

Comment: actually if user press more than 5 enters then it displays scroll bar, that i need to avoid and need to restrict the user only for 5 enters and in 5th line user will be enter not more than 15 chars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sahil_kapoor/9c5Ag/) and here is the code:

```
function getLineNumber()
{
    var t = $("#textareaId")[0];
    var lineIndex = t.value.substr(0, t.selectionStart).split("\n").length-1;

    //alert the characters in line
    alert(t.value.substr(0, t.selectionStart).split("\n")[lineIndex].length);
}

$("#textareaId").keypress(function() {
  getLineNumber();
});
```

Another approach is in this updated [**jsfiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/sahil_kapoor/9c5Ag/1/)

```
function getLineNumber()
{
    var t = $("#textareaId").val().split("\n");
    var lineIndex = (t.length)-1
    alert(t[lineIndex].length);
}

$("#textareaId").keypress(function() {
  getLineNumber();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add just a little css to solve your problem?

Option a: no scroll bar, text area extends:

```
textarea {
overflow:auto;
}
```

Option b: no scroll bar, text area stays the same:

```
textarea {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Does that help?